# Как сделать вкл\выкл сетевого подключения?

Tags: mac, lan, delphi

Всем тепла и бобра.
Накодил программку, меняет MAC на локальном ПК.
Но MAC применяется или после ребута или после вкл\откл сетевого подключения.
Вопрос, по которому не смог найти информацию в сети.
Итак, вопрос: как сделать вкл\выкл сетевого подключения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выполните в командной строке:

```
netsh interface set interface name="Имя сетевого адаптера" disable
netsh interface set interface name="Имя сетевого адаптера" enable
```

Если есть вопросы, как это делается, смотрим справку по функции `CreateProcess`.

Comment: что-то подобное про wmic писали...

Comment: ещё по теме:  
`Wmic nic get name, index  //(получим Х)
Wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=[X] call disable  
Wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=[X] call enable  `